# Prevent Antd Modal from scrolling to the top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Ant Design (version 4.22.8) and Next.js (version 12.3.4) and I have a Modal component that's shown when a button is clicked. However, the modal is currently scrolling to the top of the page rather than overlaying the content that's currently on the screen.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```js
<Modal visible={isModalVisible} title={title} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
  <div>Content</div>
</Modal>
```

What are some ways to prevent an Antd Modal from scrolling to the top of the page when it's made visible?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Antd Modal from scrolling to the top of the page, it's necessary to specify a container where the Modal will be rendered, instead of using the default behavior which uses the `body` element.

In the case of Next.js, the container for the Modal should be `#__next`. You can specify this using the `getContainer` prop, like this:

```js
<Modal getContainer='#__next' visible={isModalVisible} title={title} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
  <div>Content</div>
</Modal>
```

By doing this, the Modal should be shown on top of the current content without scrolling to the top of the page.